# Spinner malfunctioning on Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

My Android Project Build Target is 5.1.1 API 22

This app seems to work for every OS version except Lollipop. Lollipop restructures the height of some activities (negating the scrollable layout) as well as disrupts the spinners.

Clicking a specific position on a spinner will input a different position in the app. I'm not sure why and I don't know how to fix this. In some cases, even if you click a button on the spinner, it registers the bottom most visible button on the spinner. For some spinners, it won't allow the user to scroll at all.

One of my malfunctioning spinner codes is like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String>adapterl4 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,hbmlevel){ 
            public boolean isEnabled(int position){
                displayData(position);
                return true;
            }
        };
selecthbm = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.selecthbmlvl);
adapterl4.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
selecthbm.setAdapter(adapterl4);
selecthbm.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

I've also tried using a global variable for the function `displayData` but I still get the same results.

The app is a very basic app that you can download [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ccpackage.castleclashcalculator) and is running on Java Compiler Compliance level 1.7

The beginning of my xml looks like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="#C2DFFF">

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

displayData:

```
public void displayData(int pos){

    herolvlTV.setText(hbmherolvl[pos]);
    hbmshardTV.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.shards)+" " +String.valueOf(hbmshards[pos]));
    hbmexpTV.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.maxexp)+" " +String.valueOf(hbmmaxexp[pos]));
}
```

Comment: What is method `displayData` does?

Comment: @fRoStBiT It just setText for some textviews

Comment: Why are you doing it in `isEnabled()`? You should do it in `getView()`.

Comment: @fRoStBiT For some other spinners, I actually disable it based on positions. I just kept the code consistent for all my spinners. Are you suggesting that `isEnabled()` doesn't function properly on Lollipop?

Comment: I think this method shouldn't have side effects. It may be called in different conditions on different versions of Android. Probably this is the reason of incorrect behavior.

Comment: @fRoStBiT Okay do you know what will work? I don't have lollipop available at the moment, so I have to always ask someone else to test for me. Do you think I just need to use `setOnItemSelectedListener` for the spinner?

Comment: @fRoStBiT You were correct about the isEnabled function causing problems. If you have a reasonable explanation, please post it.

Comment: material spinner working great from api level 9 to 22, check [link](https://github.com/ganfra/MaterialSpinner)

Comment: for libraries, you can get "nineoldandroids" from here, [link](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids/downloads) and just need to add library project "appcompat-v7"

Comment: @krikara Why not create your own Spinner Adapter class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the issue :

```
ArrayAdapter<String>adapterl4 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,hbmlevel){ 
            public boolean isEnabled(int position){
                displayData(position);
                return true;
            }
        };
```

The `isEnabled` function simply does not work on Lollipop. The solution is to change `selecthbm.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);` into `selecthbm.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){...});` and remove the `isEnabled` function in its entirety.

I don't know why the `isEnabled` function doesn't work though. If anyone wants to provide an explanation, I can award the bounty.

Answer (score 2):

The implementation in lollipop n pre lollipop are different, though I can't analyse your code and provide a ready made solution, I hope u find ur solution here

https://blog.danielbetts.net/2015/01/02/material-design-spinner-toolbar-style-fix/