# How to use ArrayAdapter isEnabled on Android Lollipop?

Tags: android, android-spinner

When using an ArrayAdapter, I was able to use the function isEnabled for all the Android versions prior to 5.0.0. However, in Lollipop, the isEnabled function manages to break all my spinners by not registering the user clicked positions correctly.

Am I using this isEnabled function wrong? How can I fix this?

```
ArrayAdapter<String>adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,paths) {

            @Override      
            public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
                if(slider1Position < position)
                    return false;
                else 
                    return true;

        };
```

Comment: You should not override `isEnabled()` in Android 5.0. If the method returns false, the dividers for the item disappear and can cause user input to not register.

Comment: @frgnvola Yeah, so what alternatives do I have? I want to disable certain slider positions based on the position of another slider.

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30315935/spinner-malfunctioning-on-lollipop) thread

Comment: @frgnvola Hmm, his answer only shows how to create a Spinner for Lollipop. It doesn't show how to implement spinner positions.